# setdefault() on suds soap dict results

Tags: python, soap-client, suds

Given the following generic code:

```
def soapQuery():
    soapuser = "Base64String"
    soappass = "Base64String"
    soapurl = 'https://url/file.ext?wsdl'
    ntlm = WindowsHttpAuthenticated(username=soapuser, password=soappass)
    client = Client(soapurl, transport=ntlm)
    result = client.service.method(something='somethingtosearchfor')
    soapfiltered = []
    for record in result.SoapRecord:
        soapfiltered.extend((str(record.value1), str(record.value2), str(record.value3), str(record.value4)))
    return zip(*[iter(soapfiltered)]*4)
```

When ran I get the following error:

> AttributeError: SoapRecord instance has no attribute 'value3'

*MOST* of `result.SoapRecord`'s returned will contain all 4 `record.value`'s but some do not have this. Is there a way to set a default value to be returned like `None` or `Null`? I have tried throwing `record.setdefault('value3', None)` in there but it does not work. Any and all help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there is no `Null` in Python and the dict's `setdefault`'s default default is `None`. Btw, dictionaries cannot be accessed through the dot operator in Python (sadly, I miss the feature from JS) so basically...I don't think `record` is a dictionary, but rather an object instead. To check if an object has a property, you can do `hasattr(record, 'value1')` for example.

Now with that all in mind, to keep everything to a single expression, you could do something like this:

`hasattr(record, 'value1') and str(record.value1) or None`

This is a boolean expression and in Python, you can evaluate boolean expressions without fully casting the values to bools. So that expression will give you either the value of `str(record.value1)` or simply `None`.

Sorry if anything in this answer is wrong, I'm not familiar with the Soap library.

**Edit:** As @plaes has noted in the comments, `getattr(record, 'value1', None)` is a much shorter and easier way of doing it. Thank you plaes :)

Comment: `getattr(record, 'value1', None)` would be even shorter.

Comment: @plaes Thanks, I've made an edit to my answer and I gave you credit.